# no method configure in Server object (Socket.io)

Tags: django, node.js, socket.io

I trying repeat [this solution](http://maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/) in my localhost. But something wrong with installing Socket.io because it look like there is no method configure in Socket.io module

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
console.log (io.configure)

var cookie_reader = require('cookie');

//Configure socket.io to store cookie set by Django
io.configure(function(){
    io.set('authorization', function(data, accept){
        if(data.headers.cookie){
            data.cookie = cookie_reader.parse(data.headers.cookie);
            return accept(null, true);
        }
        return accept('error', false);
    });
    io.set('log level', 1);
});
```

Log: undefined

TypeError: Object # has no method 'configure' ...

Comment: The guide you're following was written for Socket.IO 0.9.x. If you've installed Socket.IO 1.0.x, which has since been released, you should read through the [Migration Guide](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/).

Comment: Thank you. So, I should now use method "use" instead

Answer (score 2):

The configure function has been deprecated. You should pass in configuration (as an options object) when you initialize your socket IO server like such ...

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
  'authorization' : function(data, accept) {
    // authorization logic
  });
});
```

See the official API for more info: http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#